# JsonResult with Html encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to return a JsonResult, which contains some HTML.

so, something like:

```
return Json(new { id="guid", html="<param id='id'/>" });
```

However, when I get the result back , the angle brackets are encoded as u003e, u003c
, etc..

I tried various encoders but can't figure this one out. Anyone run into this?

I can return a Content(string) with the Response.ContentType = "application/json" without this issue, but my json object is pretty complex and I would prefer to return a JsonResult if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: The part "Content(string) with the Response.ContentType = "application/json"" was pure gold. It would have saved me some hours if seen earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That's just Unicode. Once you show it in the browser it will look fine (if the browser is your client application).

Comment: What if I want to return and display raw HTML, and I don't want any encoding? Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is done to prevent potential XSS attacks by inserting malicious HTML tags in your data. It shouldn't have a functional difference for you. `"\uxxxx"` represents the same character as the unencoded version.